# My draft in Outlook doesn't allow editing?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am trying to edit a draft, but this is the message I get:

> Due to the size of this email, we've turned off Editor temporarily.

What do I need to do to enable editing??

Comment: [Adjust the size of your image in your signature.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-on-the-web-due-to-the-size-of-this-email/bf68098f-5d30-4615-8808-3a0e64bc1e34) if that’s unacceptable have your system administrator increase the size limit

Comment: It also might be attachments.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, this error is usually caused by large image presented in the signature. So if it happens that the problematic draft has a signature with image, try removing the image and see it helps.

Besides, considering that the error is often seen in OWA, so if you are referring to Outlook on the web by "Outlook", it's also suggested to open a private browser window and check the result.